# R : Changing Labels position in a pie chart with ApexCharter

Tags: r, graphics, label, apexcharts

I am using the `ApexCharter` library for pie charts and I would like to push the displayed labels closer to the center as they seem too "off".

[image: Basically what I want to do with the labels]

I tried to tweak the offset and textAnchor parameters using negative values in both ax_dataLabels and pie_opts, but it never changed anything. Am I using the wrong parameter or putting it in the wrong place ?

Here is my latest attempt :

```
library(dplyr)
library(apexcharter)

dummy_data <- tibble(Fruit = c("Orange", "Apple", "Tomato", "Blueberry"),
                     n = c(6, 4, 3, 5))

dummy_plot <- apex(dummy_data, type = "pie", mapping = aes(x = Fruit, y = n)) %>%
  ax_dataLabels(textAnxhor = "start", offsetX = -50, enabled = TRUE, style = list(fontSize = "16px")) %>%
  ax_title(text = "Dummy Render", align = "top", style = list(fontSize = "18px")) %>%
  ax_legend(position = "bottom") %>% 
  ax_colors(c('#EE9B00', '#116702', '#AE2012', '#0034FF')) %>%
  ax_plotOptions(pie_opts(dataLabels = list(offset = -50)))

dummy_plot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a small update to your existing code.
In ax_plotOptions(pie = pie_opts(dataLabels = list(offset = -50))), explicitly call pie = pie_opts because there is no pie_opts argument in ax_plotOptions()

```
dummy_data <- tibble(Fruit = c("Orange", "Apple", "Tomato", "Blueberry"),
                     n = c(6, 4, 3, 5))

apex(dummy_data, type = "pie", mapping = aes(x = Fruit, y = n)) %>%
  ax_dataLabels(style = list(fontSize = "16px")) %>%
  ax_title(text = "Dummy Render", align = "top", style = list(fontSize = "18px")) %>%
  ax_legend(position = "bottom") %>% 
  ax_colors(c('#EE9B00', '#116702', '#AE2012', '#0034FF')) %>% 
  ax_plotOptions(pie = pie_opts(dataLabels = list(offset = -50)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! So it was a parameter that I was missing. Does it work like this in ApexCharter with only the pie charts or for all the other chart (column, boxplot, etc) as well ?

Comment: In the documentation for ax_plotOptions(). It shows the first parameter is ax. Since you weren't  calling the pie parameter, it thought you were trying to use the ax parameter. If creating a bar (column) plot, you would explicitly call the bar parameter. ax_plotOptions(
  ax,
  bar = NULL,
  heatmap = NULL,
  radialBar = NULL,
  pie = NULL,
  bubble = NULL,
  boxPlot = NULL,
  ...
)